# .htaccess rewrite issue on iPhone

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect (www and non-www).olddomain.com to www.newdomain.com, and newdomain.com to www.newdomain.com

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=Permanent]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newdomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=Permanent]
```

These rules appear to work for all browsers except for Safari on the iPhone - it works on the iPad. iPhone redirects to `www.newdomain.com/http://www.newdomain.com/` when going to `olddomain.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting ... Let's try be more specific/accurate. If this will not help -- please provide real domain names so I can look at actual http headers.

But before you are going to do this -- please clear your browser caches/restart (on iPhone) if possible -- modern browsers (at least desktop ones) do cache 301 redirects .. and if your initial rewrite rule went wrong, browser may still use that cached redirect.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(olddomain\.com|newdomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Final domain is the same for both rules, so I have joined them into single rule.

Comment: cleared the history and it seemed to work good - thanks. However on my iPhone it is redirecting www.olddomain.com but not olddomain.com. I'm going to try on another iPhone and see how I go with that but reckon this has solved it. Thanks again.